# Progress newbie question: where are the error codes?

Tags: compiler-errors, runtime-error, openedge, progress-4gl

I've just started programming in Progress, where I stumbled upon following compilation error (freely translated from Dutch to English):

> -1 wrong. Non-negative constant needed. (3493)

This is caused by the following line of code:

```
skip (-1)
```

This obviously is correct: it makes no sense to enter a negative number of empty lines. What interests me is the error code 3493: the helpfile, added to the programming environment, does not have a complete list of them (at least, the search feature did not show any results for 3493), and also the first google result (knowledgebase.progress.com) seems not to give any useful information.

Where can I find a complete list of error codes (compilation and runtime errors), used in Progress programming language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a little bit more details about the error messages in the "Help" menu of the classical procedure editor under "Messages".

[image]

And then you could paste the (english) error message into the search field at https://knowledgebase.progress.com/ returning various articles there. In this particular case, I'm afraid the compiler message is very generic and might not point you straight into the SKIP phrase.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually possible to access the descriptions programmatically. Accessing the help menu is of course easier but if you want to program something around this, you can.

Progress knowledgebase has an article around this found [here](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/19758)